# oracledb nodejs package getConnection('hr') method hang after few hours

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have created the express server application which connect to oracle database in order to perform DB operations. That application works fine in dev environment and then I published it in ubuntu vm using pm2. Initially it works fine but after few hours getConnection('hr') method hang the request.

Inside application, First I create the oracledb connection pool at the startup of the express app.
Here is the code for connection pool.

```
const initialize = async () => {
    const pool = await oracledb.createPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        connectString: 'x.x.x.x:1521/sampledev',
        poolMin: 5,
        poolMax: 10,
        poolIncrement: 1,
        poolAlias: "hr",
    });

    console.log("Connected to the oracle db pool");
}
```

Here is the endpoint that use oracle connection.

```
app.get('/dbstatus', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        oracleConnApps = await oracledb.getConnection('hr');
        console.log("DB Connected")

        // do stuff

        res.status(200).send({ status: true, data: "OK" });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("CATCH EXECUTE")
        console.log({ status: true, data: err.message })
        res.status(400).send({ status: false, data: err.message });
    } finally {
        console.log("FINALLY EXECUTE")
        if (oracleConnApps) await oracleConnApps.close();
    }
})
```

After few hours getConnection method hang the server and it does not trigger the catch block.

I used oracledb: 6.2.0 version and thin mode to connect DB.

Comment: Update your question with the version of node-oracledb in use.  If it's 6, also mention if you are using [Thick mode](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode).  Check your [pool statistics](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-monitoring).  Review [Always Use Connection Pools — and How](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/always-use-connection-pools-and-how-909bc2c65444).

Comment: I used oracledb: 6.2.0 version and thin mode to connect DB. @ChristopherJones

Comment: This is now being followed up at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1626